# How does the runonce registry key run commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, cmd.exe

Out of curiosity, and to assist in testing the run-once key, I was wondering what program runs the string placed in runonce or just the run keys in general.

Is it powershell or cmd.exe or what? I'd like to know so I can tailor my syntax accordingly.

Comment: it executes via a program called `runonce.exe` (aka the RunOnce Wrapper), so the interpreter it uses should be specified if you want a particular behavior. Otherwise assume it takes the same semantics as invoking a program from DOS (and I do mean DOS). if you need a specific interpreter, invoke it.

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding resources on DOS that don't just tell me that it's only surviving relative is `cmd.exe`. Could you get me a reference for DOS if you know one off the top of your head?

Comment: Also, you should post your comment as an answer: I'll take it.